# What is the proper URLencoder encoding to turn " into %22?

Tags: java, urlencode, apache-httpclient-4.x

I have the following URL:

https://api-test.company.com/contacts?q=email="jlowder@company.com"

I am parsing it using:

```
String URL = "https://api-test.company.com/contacts?" + URLEncoder.encode("q=email=jlowder@company.com", "UTF-8");
```

I have also tried "ISO-8859-1", but both return this for my URL:

https://api-test.homeaway.com/contacts?q%3Demail%3Djlowder%40homeaway.com

In order to receive the correct response from my server, I need the url to be:

https://api-test.company.com/contacts?q=email=%22jlowder@company.com%22

The %22 is the " " marks around the email address.

How do I go about forming the correct URL?  None of the examples I can find do this..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you really want this, then you have to put the quotes also into the string:

```
String URL = "https://api-test.company.com/contacts?q=email=" + URLEncoder.encode("\"jlowder@company.com\"", "UTF-8");
```

gives:
    `https://api-test.company.com/contacts?q=email=%22jlowder%40company.com%22`

btw.: You want to name that String `url`, not `URL`.

Comment: Note: You don't encode the whole query part, only the *values* like Udo did. Otherwise you end up with encoded reserved characters (`q%3Demail`).